# accessing viewbag in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

net MVC. I have assigned a list of objects to the viewbag property can anyone please tell me as to how i can get the list in the view to use it in the drop down list? here is my controller code & view code

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult GetSection(int sectionId,int contactId)
        {
            ContactDetailSectionModel contactDetailSection = new ContactDetailSectionModel { SectionId = sectionId,ContactId=contactId };
            contactDetailSection.FetchAllSubsections();

            ContactDetailSectionModel customSections = new ContactDetailSectionModel();
            customSections.FetchCustomSubSections();

            if(customSections != null && customSections.ContactDetailSubSections != null)
            {
                ViewBag.CustomSubSections = customSections.ContactDetailSubSections;
            }

            return PartialView("~/Views/Contacts/Details/EditSection.cshtml", contactDetailSection);
        }
```

View Code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContactDetailSubSections[1], new SelectList(ViewBag.CustomSubSections , "Name", "Name",Model.ContactDetailSubSections[1].Name)) 
 @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ContactDetailSubSections[1].Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first parameter in your `@Html.DropDownlist` should be string or some scalar quantity it cannot be a collection.

Comment: No i got it. I cast the viewbags property into a list. Thanks for the help